# How do I retrieve Account fields from Event in LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, html, sobject

I am generating a table of Events by looping a List of Events and need to populate rows with fields that don't belong to the Event object. More specifically, I need to display Account.Name and Account.BillingCity among the other Event fields. How could I retrieve those fields and render them inside the table row?

Please check below code for further info:

```
<template for:each={eventList} for:item="event">
    <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={event.Id}>
        <td>
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="account-name">???</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="event-location">{event.Location}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="event-type">{event.Type}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="account-billing-city">???</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="account-id">{event.WhatId}</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: How is eventList being populated?  Are you calling an apex controller method?  If so, please post the apex code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a SOQL in your apex that uses relationship queries using the `AccountId` field.

The below query works on Event Object

```
SELECT event.account.name, 
   event.activitydate 
FROM event 
LIMIT 10
```

If you are looking for Custom Objects then you can use the [TYPEOF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm) expression in your SOQL

Something on below lines

```
  SELECT Id,

   WhatId,

    TYPEOF What

    WHEN CustomObject__c THEN Field1__c, Field2__c

   END

  FROM Event

  WHERE WhatId In (SELECT Id

                FROM CustomObject__c)
```

You can access the values using the below syntax, assuming you have the `event` as the variable name that has other event fields in your LWC component.

```
event.Account.Name
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How could I reference those fields in html then?

Comment: event.Account.Name will give you Account Name and same way event.Account.BillingState and so forth

Comment: I need them to be populated in Apex and then displayed in LWC. How would you assign a value to Account.Name from the query you wrote?

Comment: The response variable will have a field event.Account.Name for you automatically because of the query

Comment: Activities have an Account field. No need for TYPEOF here: `SELECT Account.BillingCity, Account.BillingState FROM Task`. This relationship is automatically populated from either WhoId or WhatId when the activity belongs to a Case, Opportunity, Contact, etc. Using TYPEOF would require you to access this as `record.What.BillingCity` and `record.What.BillingState` instead.

Comment: @sfdcfox You are right! I missed that for Account a field exists already.